# Parse xml from Ruby script within php failing with StartTag: invalid element name &lt;/Envelope&gt;

Tags: php, ruby, xml, xml-parsing

I have a Ruby script which does a query to a .NET ASP server and gets the result as a string of XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <QueryServicesResponse>
      <QueryServicesResult>
        <Date>2016-01-01</Date>
        <serviceList>
          <service>
            <uuid>10264b70-87ee-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611</uuid>
            <flight>EZY0000</flight>
            <originName>London Heathrow</originName>
            <originShort>LHR</originShort>
            <destinationName>London Stansted</destinationName>
            <destinationShort>STN</destinationShort>
            <scheduledDeparture>2016-01-01T14:00:00</scheduledDeparture>
            <scheduledArrival>2016-01-01T14:30:00</scheduledArrival>
          </service>
        </serviceList>
      </QueryServicesResult>
    </QueryServicesResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is the section of the ruby scrip which deals with the returned body;

```
# Post the request
resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)

# Output the results
doc = Nokogiri::XML(resp.body)
doc.remove_namespaces!
puts doc
```

The ruby script is called via a php file with the following code;

```
<?php
$xml = exec("ruby test.rb EZY0000",($results));

$xmlparse = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    echo $xmlparse;
?>
```

But php Throws the following errors when trying to parse the result;

> `PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error :
>   StartTag: invalid element name`
>   `PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): &lt;/Envelope&gt;`

I'm trying to parse the xml into a `SimpleXMLElement Object` I've been trying all sorts of things over the past few days but am stuck or blind to the problem now. I've tried `htmlspecialchars` but that didn't help either.

The only thing I can think of is this has something to do with the string coming from the ruby script even though it appears to be, and validates as proper xml.

If I take the xml above and use the following php code then everything works as expected and I get the desired result;

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <QueryServicesResponse>
      <QueryServicesResult>
        <Date>2016-01-01</Date>
        <serviceList>
          <service>
            <uuid>10264b70-87ee-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611</uuid>
            <flight>EZY0000</flight>
            <originName>London Heathrow</originName>
            <originShort>LHR</originShort>
            <destinationName>London Stansted</destinationName>
            <destinationShort>STN</destinationShort>
            <scheduledDeparture>2016-01-01T14:00:00</scheduledDeparture>
            <scheduledArrival>2016-01-01T14:30:00</scheduledArrival>
          </service>
        </serviceList>
      </QueryServicesResult>
    </QueryServicesResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Which gives me;

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [QueryServicesResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [QueryServicesResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Date] => 2016-01-01
                            [serviceList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [service] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [uuid] => 10264b70-87ee-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611
                                            [flight] => EZY0000
                                            [originName] => London Heathrow
                                            [originShort] => LHR
                                            [destinationName] => London Stansted
                                            [destinationShort] => STN
                                            [scheduledDeparture] => 2016-01-01T14:00:00
                                            [scheduledArrival] => 2016-01-01T14:30:00
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So how can I get the xml from my ruby script into a valid object which I can manipulate in php? Someome offline said I should try and do it all in Rails - but I'm not ready for anything like that much of a challenge at the moment.

Comment: You should post your ruby script as well. It seems like your ruby script encodes special html entites.

Comment: Just updated the question with the part of the script that deal with the body response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a hint from [@slowjack2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3940126/slowjack2k) I re-looked at the Ruby file which generates the response.

`doc = Nokogiri::XML(resp.body)` Which I changed to become `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(resp.body)` and low and behold it now works and returns a valid xml object in php as expected.